# How to call mysql store procedure in php?

Tags: php, stored-procedures

I have created stored procedures in mysql and now i want to use them in php script.

For using stored procedure through php, i am using this code:

```
 $query = "call authenticateUser('$username')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

But this is showing error of  command is not sync.

Pls someone tell me how to call stored procedure in php.

Comment: @Akam does that really make a difference? I just did a simple test and it didn't seem to...if it does make a difference, it must depend on configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$query = "CALL authenticateUser('" . $username . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: this will not run , you have to use `'` around for `$username`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar it is there.

Comment: @MadanSapkota its showing me error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @MadanSapkota is there any way to close the procedure after using it in php

Comment: @KalpanaDixit, that means you have no permission to run `STORE PROCEDURE` in your database server, check the permissions or ask your hosting support people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use statement like this:

$query = "call authenticateUser($username)";

with double quote there is no need of separation.